# How to map the file path to the src as a root in react React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, tsconfig

I'm implementing unit tests with React Testing Library, and it is giving errors while testing components.

In Component (tsx file) I used (or imported) other components without using relating path. the imports look something like below

`import {add} from 'components/sum';`

and I'm using the above component in `src/taskpane/dashboard.tsx` file.

this works fine while executing code in browser. but fails to map it in RTL unit testing.

my tsconfig looks like below

```js
{

  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5",

    "module": "esnext",

    "moduleResolution": "node",

    "allowJs": true,

    "jsx": "react",

    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable"],

    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,

    "strict": true,

    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "resolveJsonModule": true,

    "sourceMap": true,

    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,

    "outDir": "dist",

    "noImplicitReturns": true,

    "pretty": true,

    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],

    "baseUrl": "src",

    "paths": {

      "@assets/*": ["../assets/*"]

    }

  },

  "include": ["src"]

}
```